# Is there a way to add WAKE_LOCK to TWA?

Tags: android-manifest, android-wake-lock, trusted-web-activity, twa

I am using [GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) as a base for a radio streaming website.
The problem is that the audio stops streaming after the app is held in the background for around 15 minutes.

Is there a way to set the `WAKE_LOCK` or `keepScreenOn` properties in the Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but the [Screen Wake Lock API](https://web.dev/wakelock/) is currently in Origin Trial and should solve that when the feature launches (expected Chrome 84).